# @ViewChild within ngSwitch is undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access a template reference within some nested structural directives:

```
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="currentIndex">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let panel of panels; index as panelIndex;">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="panelIndex">
          <ng-container #visiblePanel *ngComponentOutlet="panel; injector: injector"></ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

I try to reference the component with:

```
  @ViewChild('visiblePanel') currentPanel: WizardPanelComponent;
```

I've also tried `id` and `Component` selectors.  Basically, it's always undefined:

```
  // Button press
  onNext() {
    this.data = this.currentPanel.data;  // this.currentPanel is undefined
    ...
  }
```

Is there some way to get a reference in ts to the currently switched component?

Comment: How many panels are visible?

Comment: Only one `[ngSwitch]="currentIndex"`.  If I remove access to the `@ViewChild` I can cycle through the panels.

Comment: Try `@ViewChild(WizardPanelComponent) currentPanel: WizardPanelComponent;`.

Comment: you're redefining `#visiblePanel` variable at the each itteration, looks weird

Comment: I did try that, I gave it another run for sanity's sake and still undefined.

Comment: @WildDev You can `#ref` each switch case since there's only one uncommented at any time.  However, even a `WizardPanelComponent` selector yields undefined.

Comment: You could try with `@ViewChildren(WizardPanelComponent)`, subscribing to the `QueryList.changes` event. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51730156/1009922).

Comment: The change event never emits.  It seems the selector just won't line up with the DOM.

Comment: @Anthony, seems to be that's expected behavior. It gonna work once it assigned outside the loop. The closest stuff there exists is `panel;                         injector: injector; content: myContent` third "content" option. Guess, it would be most preferable way to redesign this block

Comment: Thanks, my research seemed to demonstrate that references of `componentOutlet `were a no-go.  I went back to a `ComponentFactory` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need ngSwitch. So change the code as

```
  <ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let panel of panels; index as panelIndex;">
        <ng-container *ngIf="panelIndex === currentIndex">
          <ng-container #visiblePanel *ngComponentOutlet="panel; injector: injector"></ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: That's a good simplification, but it didn't solve the undefined issue.  I still can't select the component outlet with ref, or type.